# ссылка на фото не кликается

Tags: php, html, css, style

сколько не искал ошибку не смог найти, блока вроде нету
php:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo');
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 180px;
}
  .mainmenu {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  box-shadow: 3px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding: 20px;
}
.mainmenu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


.topmenu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 55px;
  float: right;
  word-spacing: -10px;

}
.topmenu li {display: inline-block;}
.topmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  transition:.3s linear;
  
}
.topmenu a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #F73E24;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6.5px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s linear;
}
.topmenu a:hover:before {opacity: 1;}
@media (max-width: 660px) {
.topmenu {
  float: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainmenu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.topmenu a {padding: 0 10px;}
.topmenu a:before {transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-6px);}
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.topmenu li {display: block;}
}


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Libre+Baskerville');
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(154,154,154);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,.8));
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  word-spacing: -1px;
}
.topmenu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.topmenu > li > a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.topmenu > li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.topmenu li:hover a:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20px);
  transition: .3s;
}
.topmenu > li:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.submenu a {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: .3s linear;
}
.submenu a:hover {background: #e8e8e8;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Tush 1153
</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="mainmenu">
  <a class="logo" href="tush.php"><img href="tush.php" src="logo.png" width="250" height="200"></a>
  <ul class="topmenu">
    <li><a href="" class="down">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="study.php" class="down">Обучение</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
 <li><a href="narashivanie_lessons.php">Наращивание ресниц</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ламинирование ресниц</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Бровист</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Сам себе бровист</a></li>
 </ul>
    </li>
 <li><a href="" >Сертификаты</a></li>
    <li><a href="" >Галерея</a></li> 
 <li><a href="" >О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="down">Контакты</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
 <li><a href="">Как нас найти?</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Свяжитесь с нами</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Картинка чем-то перекрывается. Если убрать `body:before`, то кликается.

Comment: И всё-таки не забывайте про `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: помогло спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ссылке допиши 2 свойства.

```
a.logo {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
display: inline-block;
height: 180px;
}
```